# How to calculate the rotation angle to top of a pie chart?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, transform, pie-chart

I'm trying to rotate a pie chart wheel when a user selects a slice and get the slice to stop at the top of the wheel

```
    // start from the middle of the slice angle
    let startAngle = self.slicesArray[index].angle / 2
    // end at top of chart
    let endAngle = //?
    let angleDifference = //?
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, -angleDifference)
    })
```

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information to know in your question, but wouldn't `endAngle` be a fixed value, such as 0 or π / 2?

Comment: Sorry for lack of info, it should be fixed, I already tried these two values and still the wheel only rotates a bit and doesn't get to top.

Comment: Having a closer look at your calculation of `startAngle`, it is just half the angular width of the pie slice and doesn't take the angular position into account.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 3/2 π for endAngle? the difference is obviously endAngle - startAngle